# How to mock a protected class whos instance is used by the tested method in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, protected

I have a public POJO class whos constructor is protected & its setters are protected/private as well.
The only thing that is public is the getters.

```
public class RequestInfo {
    
    private String user;
    private String date;
    private String action;
    

    protected RequestInfo(String user, String date, String action) {
        this.user = user;
        this.date = date;
        this.action = action;
    }
    
    public String getUser(){
        return user;
    }
    ...
    ...
    private void setUser(String user){
        this.user = user;
    }
    ..
    ..
}
```

I want to write a JUnit test which tests a method, that gets as a parameter an instance of the POJO class I have mentioned in the beginning.

```
public String getReport(RequestInfo requestInfo){
    String requestUser = requestInfo.getUser();
    String requestDate = requestInfo.getDate();
    String requestAction = requestInfo.getAction();
    ....
    ....
}
```

This complicates things for me, because I want to mock this instance in order to test the method as needed, but I can't mock it because:

1. I can't just create a new instance of the class and insert my mocked values because the **constructor is protected.**

```
@Test
public void getReportTest(){
    RequestInfo requestInfo = new RequestInfo("john", "12DEC22", "addUser");
    String report = ReportsManager.getReport(requestInfo);
    assertEquals(.......)
    .....
}
```

2. I can't mock it using `Mockito.mock(RequestInfo.Class)` because although it will create a mock of the class, but everything inside of it (fields) will be nulled, so the tested method, which relies on the info that the instance stores, will fail.

I can make the constructor public, but I wrote it as protected for a reason, and I don't want to break my design just because of one or two tests.

**I have wrote the codes as an example to clarify my needs, please address to the general idea and not for these specific code samples**

I'll be glad to get tips,
thanks.

Comment: I don't get point 2. If you mock it, it's an "empty" mock: all methods return the default value for their type. If you want your mock to return different values, you have to set it up with `when(mockObj.methodCall()).thenReturn(yourDesiredValue)`. And what prevents you from putting the test in the same package as the class itself? `protected` members can be accessed from within the same package

Comment: You must have a way to construct RequestInfo in your production code - be it a factory method, subclass with public constructor etc. Why don’t you use one of those in your unit test?

Comment: @knittl as I said, I can't use `thenReturn` because I have no desired value to return. I can't construct my desired `RequestInfo` instance because its constructor is protected. Regarding your 2nd question - It's not good practice to place tests in the same package as the src code base files. I'm talking about a mS.

Comment: @Lesiak I do have a way to construct this class in my production code - but I construct it in the same package. I construct it and then pass it to `getReport` which is also in the same package.

Comment: @NoobCoder why is it bad practice to have tests in the same package? Almost all tests that I know are placed in the same package as their tested classes (but in a different source set). In your question you write "but everything inside of it (fields) will be nulled, so the tested method, which relies on the info that the instance stores, will fail." and in your comment you write "because I have no desired value to return". I read the former as "there are some values that must be returned by the instance, otherwise the test will not work" – those are your desired values.